# Multiple Java errors that I am having trouble resolving

Tags: java

My assignment requires me to print different responses for varying user inputs and I am receiving multiple errors that when I try what is suggested I receive more errors that revert my code back to its original state.

My Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {String name;
int love;
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How much love do you need?");
love = scanIn.nextLine();
for (love = 0; love < 0;)
    System.out.println("Everybody needs some love!");

for (love > 10);
    System.out.println("You cannot handle that much love!");

for (love > 0; love < 10;)
    System.out.println("I love you "
        + Integer.toString(love+ " ways"));
scanIn.close();

}
```

}

The original errors:

```
HelloMePoem.java:32: error: ';' expected
    for (love = 0; love < 0);
                           ^
HelloMePoem.java:35: error: not a statement
    for (love > 10);
              ^
HelloMePoem.java:36: error: ')' expected
            System.out.println("You cannot handle that much love!");
                                                                   ^
HelloMePoem.java:38: error: not a statement
    for (love > 0; love < 10);
              ^
HelloMePoem.java:38: error: ';' expected
    for (love > 0; love < 10);
                            ^
```

After fixing most of these errors(still unsure how to solve the "not a statement" errors). I receive these errors:

```
HelloMePoem.java:35: error: not a statement
    for (love > 10);
              ^
HelloMePoem.java:35: error: ';' expected
    for (love > 10);
                  ^
HelloMePoem.java:36: error: ')' expected
            System.out.println("You cannot handle that much love!");
                                                                   ^
HelloMePoem.java:38: error: not a statement
    for (love > 0; love < 10;)
              ^
```

Just a note: This is my first time using Java and I barely know what I'm doing

Comment: is it too hard for you to google basic java syntax for `for` loop and `if` condition statements?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these issues can be resolved by reading a simple Java tutorial.

Comment: Short (but incomplete) answer - `for` is for running a block of code over and over.  `if` is for running a block of code either _once_ or _not at all_.  I think every time you wrote `for`, you meant to write `if`.  You might also need the operators `||` (which means _or_) and `&&` (which means _and_).

Comment: OP is trying to use pattern matching, ie `when (for) variable > 10 do something`, so @DawoodibnKareem is 100% right, `for` == `if` and `;` equals `||`

Comment: Upvoted; yes it's a very basic question, but @rburrus has given plenty of information about the problems he's having, has shown his code and been open about the fact that it's a homework assignment, consequently he's got good answers below. This is infinitely higher quality than about 75% of the first questions I see. Good on your rburrus - welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck with your assignment :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

for-loops in java have a specific format which is

*for (initialization; termination;increment){

    statement(s)

}*

Above 3 parameters are optional and can be kept blank. But though they are optional you have to follow the format in which a for-loop is written.
So, if all you parameters are blank your for-loop will look like this:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    // your code goes here (b.t.w this is an infinite loop)
}
```

The problem in your code was the for-loop format and the way you were using *Integer#toString()*
I have modified your code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name;
    int love;
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How much love do you need?");

    //Scanner has nextInt() which allows you to read integers without you having to convert the type.
    love = scanIn.nextInt();
    for (love = 0; love < 0;)
        System.out.println("Everybody needs some love!");

    for (;love > 10;)
        System.out.println("You cannot handle that much love!");

    for (; love > 0 && love < 10;)
        //no need to use Integer.toString(). Just pass the variable and it will be printed.
        System.out.println("I love you " + love + " ways");

    scanIn.close();

}
```

JavaDocs Reference: [For-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: This program always prints nothing at all.  Probably not what OP had in mind.

Comment: Agreed. as every time the love would get value 0 assigned
 But the code was provided to solve the format issues.

Comment: Although this mostly correct, and it does answer the question, I'd advise @rburrus not to copy it verbatim as your answer - you won't get high marks for your assignment! This is a good explanation of how for loops work, but probably doesn't include all the elements that your assignment is intended for you to practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, I *strongly* recommend reading a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) on how looping in Java works (especially on [how the `for` loop works](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm)); I think that, once you do so, you'll see the issues here very quickly.

Your syntax `for` loops is incorrect.

The proper syntax is something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Code
}
```

For example,

```
for (love = 0; love < 0;)
```

you have no details on how the `love` variable should actually be modified. Furthermore, `love = 0; love < 0;` is trivially false.

It seems like you may be mixing up `for` and `while` loops. For example,

```
for (love > 10);
```

fundamentally makes no sense.

Also, the fact that you have a `;` right after it means that the `for` loop wouldn't do anything (even if your syntax was correct). This is a perfect illustration of why you should use `{` and `}` for code blocks.

Comment: Hang on - you commented that you voted to close this question, which means you think people shouldn't be allowed to answer it.  Yet, less than three minutes later, here you are!  Which is it?  Or do you think you should be the only person allowed to supply an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Below is just some code to help you figure out the syntax.  I took a wild stab at some of the things (like do you need a for loop or an if statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String name;
    int love;

    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How much love do you need?");

    love = scanIn.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= love; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Everybody needs some love!");
    }

    if (love > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("You cannot handle that much love!");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= love; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("I love you "
            + love + " ways");
    }

    scanIn.close();

}
```